# SQL Query, MIN isn't returning just the lowest value

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

```
Model          Make          Price
--------------------------------------
Ford            42            23454
Ford            32            21422
Ford            12            19000
GM              12            14343
GM              32            21345
GM              14            12343
BMW             32            43355
```

This is  a sample table (simplified). What I'm trying to do is find the price closest to an input for each Model. Then return the Model, Make, and Price that's closest.

For example, for $20,000. The results would be:

```
   Model  Make  Price
 ----------------------
1) Ford    12    19000        ($1000 difference)
2) GM      32    21345        ($1234 difference)
3) BMW     32    43355        ($23355 difference)
```

This is my current SQL (using Postgres):

```
SELECT model, make, price, difference
FROM (
   SELECT model, price, MIN(ABS(20000 - price)) as difference 
   FROM table
   GROUP BY model, price)
INNER JOIN ON model, price;
```

The inner isn't returning just the minimum difference but all. Not sure how to correct this.

Thanks.

Comment: this is definitely a cool question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT`:

```
SELECT t.*, ABS(20000 - price) as difference 
FROM table t
ORDER BY ABS(20000 - price)
LIMIT 3;
```

You can increase or decrease the `LIMIT` to however many rows you want.

The problem with your query is that you are joining on `model` and `price`, but not on `difference`.

EDIT:

For one row per model, use window functions:

```
SELECT t.*, ABS(20000 - price) as difference
FROM (SELECT t.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY model ORDER BY ABS(20000 - price)) as seqnum 
      FROM table t
     ) t
WHERE seqnum = 1;
ORDER BY ABS(20000 - price);
```

Comment: I think he wants it 1 row per Model. Oh I see you are working on the inr